# local storage is undefined/no value but doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

```
if (typeof localStorage["BestScore"] <= "undefined") 
{ var maxScore= localStorage["BestScore"] }
} else     localStorage["BestScore"] = 0;
    var maxScore=0;

  var newScore=false
  function drawScore(score) {
    if (newScore == true && score < maxScore) {
      newScore = false;
    }
if (score > maxScore) {
  newScore = true;
  localStorage["BestScore"] = score;
  if ([5, 10, 15, 20].indexOf(score) !== -1) {
    play(sndMedal);
  } else { 
    play(sndGain);
  }
}
maxScore = Math.max(score, maxScore);

ctx.drawImage(sheet, 146, 58, 113, 58, 
              -226, 0, 226, 116);    
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(-20, 45);
ctx.scale(0.5, 0.5);
var size = drawNbr(score, false);
ctx.restore();

// var draw medals
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(-178, 66);
if (score >= 20) { // platinum
  ctx.drawImage(sheet,220, 144, 22, 22, -22, -22, 44, 44);    
} else if (score >= 15) { // gold
  ctx.drawImage(sheet,242, 229, 22, 22, -22, -22, 44, 44);
} else if (score >= 10) { // silver
  ctx.drawImage(sheet,266, 229, 22, 22, -22, -22, 44, 44);
} else if (score >= 5) { // bronze
  ctx.drawImage(sheet,302, 137, 22, 22, -22, -22, 44, 44);
}

ctx.restore();

if (newScore) { // draw NEW
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(-60 - (size*16), 37);
  ctx.drawImage(sheet, 146, 245, 16, 7, 
                0, 0, 32, 14);    
  ctx.restore();
}

ctx.save();
ctx.translate(-20, 88);
ctx.scale(0.5, 0.5);
drawNbr(maxScore, false);
ctx.restore();
```

}

> > This is what happens when i run it when i have the maxscore = the
> >     local storage [imageshack.com/a/img691/167/28x1.png][1] and it is frozen.
> >
> > This code tries to check if the local storage best score is
> >     undefined/no value and if it is it sets maxscore to 0 if it has a
> >     value it set maxscore to the value. For some reason this code is not
> >     working please help.
>
> [1]: http://imageshack.com/a/img691/167/28x1.png

Comment: The snippet you've given is perfectly fine. Look for errors elsewhere

Comment: Why the variable maxScore is local?

Answer (score 0):

First check that `Storage` is possible or not then check that your localStorage `BestScore` object is there or not.

```
if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (!localStorage.BestScore) {
    localStorage.BestScore = 0;
    }
    var maxScore = localStorage.BestScore; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if (typeof localStorage.BestScore === 'undefined') {
    localStorage.BestScore = 0;
    var maxScore=0;
}     
else {
    var maxScore=localStorage.BestScore; 
}
```